# Is intersection of regular language and context free language is "always" context free language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, closure-properties

I have read that intersection of regular language and context-free language is always context-free. Most of the places an standard example has been used to prove this, e.g., 
\begin{align*}
L_1 &= L(a^*b^*)\\
L_2 &= \{a^nb^n\mid n\geq 0\} \quad\text{(which is context free)}\\
L_1\cap L_2 &= \{a^nb^n\mid n\geq 0\}\,.
\end{align*}
But my question is what if the regular language is finite, such as
\begin{align*}
L_1 &= \{ab\}\\
L_2 &= \{a^nb^n\mid n\geq 0\}\\
L_1\cap L_2 = \{ab\}\,. 
\end{align*}
Here intersection comes out to be finite and the language generated by intersection of both language is also finite which is regular (I know it's also context-free but regular is a stronger answer here).

What mistake am I making in understanding the concept?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18642/intersection-of-context-free-with-regular-languages

Comment: "Most of the places an standard example has been used to prove this" -- citation needed. A single example can't prove a claim such as this.

Comment: You already give yourself the answer, so I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The claim is that the intersection of a regular language and a context-free language is context-free. You've intersected a regular language ($\{ab\}$) and a context-free language ($\{a^nb^n\mid n\geq 0\}$) and the result was a context-free language ($\{a b\}$). Sure, that language is also regular but every regular language is also context-free. The statement *isn't* that the intersection of a regular language and a context-free language is a non-regular context-free language.

Analogously, the child of two mammals is a mammal. You've taken two mammals and you're saying, "Why is their child a cat? It's supposed to be a mammal."

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is in interpreting the meaning of the statement

> The intersection of a regular language and a context-free language is a context-free language.

This statement means that if $R$ is regular and $L$ is context-free then $R \cap L$ is context-free. It *doesn't* state that $R \cap L$ is not regular; this is just not part of the claim.

Your first example shows that $R \cap L$ could be not regular, but it could also be regular, as your other example shows.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. Sure, the claim doesn't say that $R\cap L$ is regular. But I think the misunderstanding is that the asker is interpreting "The intersection is context-free" to mean "The intersection is context-free and not regular."

Comment: Thanks Yuval finally able to understand the meaning of the concept.