How to demonstrate that the intersection of a context-free and a regular language is context-free?
I'm working on a theoretical computer science exercise and need some help with solving it. Here's the task:
Task:
Let $C$ be a context-free language and $R$ a regular language. Show that $C \cap R$ is context-free.
My Attempt:
I understand that context-free languages can be accepted by Pushdown Automata (PDA) and regular languages by Finite Automata (FA). My approach was to construct a new PDA that combines both automata, transitioning based on the operations of the PDA for $C$ and the state transitions of the FA for $R$. Specifically, the new PDA would work as follows:

States: Create pairs of states $(q_C, q_R)$ where $q_C$ are states from the PDA accepting $C$ and $q_R$ are states from the FA accepting $R$.
Transitions: For a transition $(q_C, a, \gamma) \rightarrow (q_C', \gamma')$ in the PDA for $C$ and a transition $(q_R, a) \rightarrow q_R'$ in the FA for $R$, the new PDA has a transition $((q_C, q_R), a, \gamma) \rightarrow ((q_C', q_R'), \gamma')$.
Accepting States: A state $(q_C, q_R)$ is accepting in the new PDA if $q_C$ is an accepting state in the PDA for $C$ and $q_R$ is an accepting state in the FA for $R$.

Question:
I am not sure if this approach covers all cases, or if there are any exceptions or special considerations I need to take into account. Can anyone provide feedback or suggest improvements to this method?

This theorem is proven in many standard textbooks on automata theory, and on this site.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18642/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71279/755.

There is one special case you must deal with. The PDA might be able to perform a $\varepsilon$-transition where the FSA can't.
