# How to create all even length words from a given CNF grammar

Tags: context-free

given CFG *G1 = {V1, Σ1, R1, S1}* in its CNF form,

I have to define a new *G5* grammar that constructs *L(G5)* using {V1, Σ1, R1, S1}:

while *L(G5)* = { x ∈ L(G1) | |x| is even }

i . e .

*L(G5)* composed of all even length words in *L(G1)*

How can I do it?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18642/755, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Closure_properties

Answer (score 4):

This is a specific application of the fact that context-free languages are closed under under intersection with a regular languages. The usual proof is to use the fact that we can find a pushdown automaton and a finite state automaton, and then for the intersection simulate the pair in parallel. This is called the product construction.

Here there is a simple solution directly on the context-free grammar. For each nonterminal $A$ introduce two copies $A_e$ and $A_o$ that together derive the same set of strings, but separated into even length and odd length respectively. The productions must be annotated with odd and even accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! 
So how can I formally define L(G5) with {V5, Σ5, R5, S5} using {V1, Σ1, R1, S1}?

Comment: The new set of nonterminals is of the form $\{ X_e, X_o \mid X\in V\}$. The productions have to be changed from $A\to BC$ into $A_x\to B_yC_z$ for a sensible choice of $x,y,z$.

Comment: Can you please write down the full new formal grammar? I have tried to do it but i got stuck

Comment: Change $A\to a$ into $A_o\to a$. Change $A\to BC$ into $A_e\to B_eC_e$ and $A_e\to B_oC_o$ and similar for $A_o$. New axiom $S_e$.

Comment: how can I define the new axiom?